# In SwiftUI, popover, sheets, and confirmation dialogs break on iPad when tapping on another dialog with a dialog open

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

On iPad, if you have a popover or confirmation dialog(which are presented as popovers) open, it's still possible to click on a button to open another popover/sheet/confirmation dialog in the background view. When doing this the second dialog won't get opened and it will never get opened even when tapping on it repeatedly. If both dialogs are popovers or confirmation dialogs it works, but you can't go from either popover or confirmation dialog to another type(including sheets). What is the best way to deal with this? Do I really need some sort of work around like a global "any dialog open" bool and for example disable all buttons when this is true? Then I would probably need custom bindings for isPresented and set this bool everywhere. Another option is to not use confirmation dialogs and popovers on iPad and replace them with sheets and alerts. Seems strange that using these components require such work arounds if that's the case.

Here is an example, if you open popover or confirmation dialog first then another type while its open it will break (sheets don't have this problem when opened first):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var popoverpresented = false
    @State var confirmationPresented = false
    @State var confirmationPresented2 = false
    @State var sheetPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button("popover") {
                popoverpresented = true
            }
            Spacer()
            Button("confirmation dialog 1") {
                confirmationPresented = true
            }
            Spacer()
            Button("confirmation dialog 2") {
                confirmationPresented2 = true
            }
            Spacer()
            Button("Sheet") {
                sheetPresented = true
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .popover(isPresented: $popoverpresented) {
            Text("First popover")
        }
        .confirmationDialog(
            "Confirmation dialog 1",
            isPresented: $confirmationPresented,
            titleVisibility: .visible
        ) {
            Button("button") {}
        } message: {
            VStack {
                Text("Some text")
            }
        }
        .confirmationDialog(
            "Confirmation dialog 2",
            isPresented: $confirmationPresented2,
            titleVisibility: .visible
        ) {
            Button("button") {}
        } message: {
            VStack {
                Text("Some text")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheetPresented) {
            Text("Sheet")
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried attaching the dialogs to the buttons instead of the VStack but doesn't help.

I am targeting iOS 16 and tested on iPad Pro (12.9 inch) simulator.

Comment: I submitted feedback FB12078831 about this, copied here http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5597349300666368

Answer (score 0):

Currently popovers must be closed before opening a sheet in swiftui. I am hopeful this will be changed in the near future, but for now you can achieve your goal by first closing the popover and then opening the sheet like the following.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var popoverpresented = false
    @State var sheetPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button("popover") {
                popoverpresented = true
            }
            Spacer()
            Button("Sheet") {
                popoverpresented = false
                sheetPresented = true
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .popover(isPresented: $popoverpresented) {
            Button("open sheet")  {
                popoverpresented = false
                sheetPresented = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheetPresented) {
            Text("Sheet")
        }
    }
}
```